# SQL in Prepared Statement throwing SQL exception

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to figure out why this code is throwing an SQL exception. When I run this code it prints "Bad SQL in customer insert ps", which is the message in that inner catch block. I've got multiple prepared statements with SQL inserts like this both in this class and also elsewhere in my application. They're all working fine. I've looked through this one over and over again, and I can't figure out why this one is throwing an exception.

```
try {
                Connection conn = DBconnection.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT customerId FROM customer WHERE customerName=\"" + name + "\";");
                System.out.println(ps.toString());
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next()) {
                    customerId = rs.getString("customerId");
                }
                try {

                    PreparedStatement customerInsert = DBconnection.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT "
                            + "INTO customer (customerName, addressId, active, createDate, createdBy, lastUpdate, lastUpdateBy)"
                            + "VALUES(\"" + name + "\", " + addressId + ", " + active + ", UTC_TIMESTAMP(), \"" + LogInController.getUserName() + "\", UTC_TIMESTAMP(), \"" + LogInController.getUserName() + "\");");

                    customerInsert.executeUpdate();

                    System.out.println(customerInsert.toString());
                    System.out.println(rs.toString());

                } catch (SQLException sq) {
                System.out.println("Bad SQL in customer insert ps");
                }

            } catch (SQLException customerIdException) {
                System.out.println("Bad SQL in customer ps");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `PreparedStatement` as though you were using `Statement`. Don't put the parameters in the SQL, put in placeholder `?` marks. Then use the various `setXyz` methods (`setString`, `setInt`, etc.) to fill in the parameters:

```
PreparedStatement customerInsert = DBconnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO customer (customerName, addressId, active, createDate, createdBy, lastUpdate, lastUpdateBy)" +
                   "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
);
customerInsert.setString(1, name);
customerInsert.setInt(2, addressId);
// ...etc. Notice that the parameter indexes start with 1 rather than 0 as you might expect
```

Comment: I'm going to try it. I have other statements that are similar to this one elsewhere in my class and program that are set up like this that do work. I'm not sure what the underlying issue is here. If I do this and it fixes my problem I'll be happy and I'll click the checkmark. Thank you! I'm somewhat new to StackOverflow.

Comment: @aforbe2: No worries, no rush. If you have others that are in the form you've shown in your question, even if they're working it's important to update them to use the form above, because the way the code in the question is written it's **wide-open** to SQL injection attacks. None of us wants to make this phone call: http://bobby-tables.com :-)

Comment: Ha ha, thank you for the comic strip. I'll keep this in mind in the future. Also thank you for being kind. I've found some devs on SO can be a little prickly. I don't know why I was getting an exception thrown, but your answer fixed my issue and I'm changing all my other statements to use set methods.